# Get input by property

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to get associated input for property? I need to focus input after model is added to array:

```
var newItem = new ChildModel();
this.childItems.push(newItem);
// and then something like this:
newItem.observableProperty.focusInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the `hasfocus` binding.  If you are willing to add a `selected` property to your `ChildModel` you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/sZnbU/

When I push an item into the observable array I set its `selected` property to `true`.  This gives it focus. Each row also has a `Select` button to allow you to select it.

When I add a new item I log the items so you can see the `selected` property changing. Finally, if you click in the input textbox, giving it focus, and then click `Log` and you'll see no "selected" items.

--

```
<span>
    New Item: <input data-bind="value:newItem" />
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
    <button data-bind="click: logItems">Log</button>
</span>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <p>
        <input data-bind="value: text, hasfocus: selected" />
        <button data-bind="click: selectItem">Select</button>
    </p>
</div>​
```

--

```
var ChildItem = function(text) {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable(text);
    self.selected = ko.observable(true);
    self.selectItem = function() {
        self.selected(true);
    }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.newItem = ko.observable('');
    self.addItem = function() {
        if (self.newItem().length > 0) {
           self.items.push(new ChildItem(self.newItem()));
           self.newItem('');
           self.logItems();
        }
    };
    self.logItems = function() {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self.items));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

​
​